# Customize admin panel component from strapi v3 plugin

Tags: reactjs, strapi, headless-cms

I am developing a local plugin for strapi V3 project and need to make modifications to some main admin panel interface components.

Taking as an example the react component `admin/src/components/LeftMenu/LeftMenuHeader/index.js`, a possible path is my plugin override it removing the default header link.

I know it is possible to create an `admin/src` folder, and put the code on there. But I do not found a way to make it from a plugin code.

Is it possible to overwrite the component Left Menu Header directly in my plugin code?